# When are .properties files loaded on JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, properties, loading

When are `.properties` files loaded on JBoss? Once and only when JBoss starts? Or are they read every time an application is deployed anew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a general answer for this, it depends on which .properties files you want to reload, i.e. which service or application is loading them.

If the .properties file is part of an application (a war or ear) they will usually be reloaded when the application is redeployed.

If they are part of the JBoss config, they are configuration for the various services that come with JBoss. These services usually start when the JBoss server starts up and read their configuration from the .properteis files as part of their individual startup process. If you want to reload the configuration from a .properties file that is used by one of these services, it may be enough to just restart that one service that uses the file, without the need to restart the whole JBoss container. There is e.g. the properties-service that you can configure to set Java system properties from .properties files. If you restart only that service by touching the file deploy/properties-service.xml, it will reload the .properties file(s) and update the Java system properties while JBoss is still running.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few property files in the JBoss directories. Each of them might is loaded by different parts of the system at different times. That might be even time-triggered (e.g. every hour) or dependent on the application(s).

If you want a more specific answer you have to be more specific which files you are interested in. And a specific version of JBoss might not hurt also.